# Displaying stored column data in table format

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the selected values in columns as table format from the database. 
I have columns name `listingsdbelements_field_name` and `listingsdbelements_field_value` in the database , i am extracting the data like this

```
$sql1 = "select listingsdb.listingsdb_id,  listingsdb.listingsdb_title, listingsdbelements.listingsdbelements_field_name, listingsdbelements. listingsdbelements_field_value from listingsdb,listingsdbelements where listingsdb.listingsdb_id IN (" . implode(',',$name) . ") AND listingsdb.listingsdb_id = listingsdbelements.listingsdb_id "; 

$result = mysql_query($sql1) or die (mysql_error());



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo $row['listingsdbelements_field_value'];

echo $row['listingsdbelements_field_name'];
}
```

I want to display it as

```
<tr><td>Field</td><td>Values</td></tr>
```

Under `Filed` i want to display `listingsdbelements_field_name`
Under `Values` i want to display `listingsdbelements_field_value`

Can somebody suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question properly:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<tr">;
    echo "<td>".$row['listingsdbelements_field_value']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['listingsdbelements_field_name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Yeah i got but i want to display only few fields in that. I mean in `listingsdbelements_field_name` i have fileds like: features, name, price, area, address...and `listingsdbelements_field_values` , i have respected values for the names. In that i want to select only few fileds ...

Comment: can you please suggest?

Comment: I am not totally sure I understand. Only rows with certain values of listingsdbelements_field_name should be displayed?

Comment: Actually In table `listingsdbelements_field_name` and `listingsdbelements_field_value` are the column names. In that i store fileds names like features, names, address.... in `listingsdbelements_field_value` column and i store features of the product infront of features in `listingsdbelements_field_name`, name in the name...... while selecting i want to select only featurs and names for eg instead of address, pin....